# jQuery re-run script when browser is re-sized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that "flys-in" a div when the page loads its position is based on the width of the window but when a user re-sizes the browser it doesn't look right and loses the effect. I'm new to jQuery is there a way to re-run a script when the browser is re-sized or a way to change my script so it will work when the browser is re-sized.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
var currWidth = $(window).width();

var element = 170; //size of the element
var put = (currWidth / 2) - element; //work out the margin left to put the element

$('#welcome').animate({left: put}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to [$(window).resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event.

```
 $(function(){
     resizeEm();
 });
 var $window = $(window);
 $window.resize(function() {
    //Run your script or invoke the function
    resizeEm();
 });

 function resizeEm(){
     var currWidth = $window.width();
     var element = 170; //size of the element
     var put = (currWidth / 2) - element; //work out the margin left to put the element
     $('#welcome').animate({left: put}, 1000);
 }
```

Resize event is gng to get triggered many times for one resize so you can keep a timer using setTimeout and do the resize once based on a arbitrary timeout value.

```
 var timeout;
 $window.resize(function() {
    //Run your script or invoke the function
   clearTimeout(timeout); //if any events fire previous existing timeout in the event queue gets cleared
   timeout = setTimeout(function(){ //create a new timeout
    resizeEm();
    }, 500); //Just giving 500 millisec delay
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wNR7/)**

Comment: This will work, but it should be noted that browsers fire "resize" events *very* quickly. Resizing a browser window even just a little bit will fire dozens of separate events. It's usually a good idea to introduce a timer mechanism to keep the number of updates down.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah that is a great point. It is going to keep on executing it. There will be many number of callbacks fired for one resize activity and with the usage of `animate` it might get ugly.